# Manage Big Query table from Google Sheet

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, airflow, data-warehouse

I have a lot of tables ETL using airflow from google sheet to big query, these tables use the write truncate method

I have a problem. these tables are used for weekly financial reporting where there is a cut off at the beginning of the week

How can I manage it so that the data sent to finance does not change when viewed in the future, while data that has been inputted on google sheets is often changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- The most obvious: Instead of using the write truncate, use the write append method to add new data to the existing table without overwriting the previous data. This requires changes to your current queries & reports.
- Create a new table for past weeks financial reporting, use the write append method to add data to this table each week. This may be easier than the former as you could introduce a "reported week" identifier as you append the most recently reported week.
- Use a scheduling tool like Apache Airflow to automate the ETL process and load data from Google Sheets to BigQuery (i.e. to avoid manual interventions and/or mistakes)
- Set up permissions and access controls to ensure that only authorized personnel can view or modify the data - and maintain this security model to ensure data integrity